# How can I make sure that gtm send the pageview fast?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am making the change from the basic analytics code to google tag manager since I need it to track impressions for certain elements. While testing when the pageview fires, I get this warning :

> "This page took a long time to send a pageview hit to Google Analytics. Users could be clicking away from your site before it records a pageview."

Google tag manager requires adding the code at the beginning of the body (I tried adding it in the header just in case it helps with that warning, but that didn't work).

Comment: Off topic, as this question isn't related to coding, but you can read the GA Support pages for suggestions to help resolve this issue: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6277326?hl=en

Comment: I read their suggestions, and it doesn't help my current need. I believe this is related to coding since the structure of where the tracking snippet is added is relevant to when the script runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably GA is not the best choice for such task. GA is well-tailored for pageviews, but not for custom actions.

I solve similar issue with http://www.devmetrics.io analytics. To track impressions for certain elements on my page: 1) add for each of this elements `trackvisible` css class 2) using `setInterval` check visibility every few seconds.

Example code using jQuery and devmetrics analytics:

```
$('.trackvisible').each(function( index ) {
    if ($(this).visible()) {
        var tag = 'element.' + $(this).attr('id');
        devmetrics.userEvent('impression', [tag]);
    }
});
```